# Why do I get 404 loading resources on server with my Vue + Flask app?

Tags: vue.js, flask, heroku, server

Here is my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: '',
  outputDir: 'flask_app_name/static',
  publicPath: '/app/flask_app_name/static/',
};
```

I deploy my app to heroku. When I try to open it I get a blank page. In the console I see:

```
GET https://app_name.herokuapp.com/app/flask_app_name/static/css/app.e544e90b.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

And this is what I got in the logs:

```
2020-07-03T07:18:47.349351+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.239.7 - - [03/Jul/2020:07:18:47 +0000] "GET /app/flask_app_name/static/css/app.e544e90b.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://app_name.herokuapp.com/"
```

But I am sure that the css (js and other) files are there. I can tell it by running command:

```
heroku run cat /app/flask_app_name/static/css/app.e544e90b.css
```

Here's to give you an idea of how my folder structure looks like:

```
flask_app_name
--__init__.py
--commands.py
--models.py
--extensions.py
--settings.py
public
--index.html
src
--assets
--components
--store
--main.js
--App.vue
Procfile
.env
package.json
vue.config.js
wsgi.py
```

`npm run build` is run on the server side automatically after push

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what worked for me

In the `vue.config.js` I set `publicPath` to `/static/`

And in `__init__.py` removed `static_url_path`  parameter from app object creation, so only `app = Flask(__name__)` left